# ANTLR 4 multiple parser rules in grammar mismatched input 'xxx' expecting 'xxx'

Tags: java, antlr4, dsl

I am newbie to ANTLR4 and DSL. I want to create my DSL. I tried basic demo to get idea of it [see here](http://www.theendian.com/blog/antlr-4-lexer-parser-and-listener-with-example-grammar/). Now I want to define multiple rules(which will represent one functionality/function in corresponding Java class) under one grammar. Where as in DSL input(text file), I want to consume rules randomly and traverse those rules (trees) only(not all rules).

```
My grammar:
grammar Hello;
sayHello  : 'hello' STRING ';' ;

welcomeMessage : 'welcome' STRING ';' ;

newTest : 'newhello' STRING ';' ;

STRING : [a-zA-Z]+ ; 

WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

---

```
public static void main( String[] args) throws Exception 
{
    ANTLRInputStream input = new ANTLRInputStream("hello world;"

         + "newhello newworld;" );

    HelloLexer lexer = new HelloLexer(input);
    CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
    HelloParser parser = new HelloParser(tokens);   
    parser.addParseListener(new MyHelloLister());

    // At runtime how to define which tree(parser function to invoke) to generate and traverse.
    // parser. sayHello(); // Error, because not traversed tree, and input is mismatched.
    // parser.welcomeMessage(); 
    parser.newTest();   

}
```

> Error: line 1:0 mismatched input 'hello' expecting 'newhello'

So, I want to know from input DSL file, which rules to invoke. Can anyone briefly give me idea about it ?

Comment: Did you run your code with `parser.newTest()` commented in or out?

Comment: What version of ANTLR are you using?

Comment: @KvanTTT, ANTLR 4.4

Answer (score 0):

Well, you call `newTest()`. The rule for newTest is this:

```
newTest : 'newhello' STRING ';' ;
```

So the parser expects something like "newhello abcdef;". But you passed "hello world;newhello newworld;". That does not start with "newhello", as the error message tells you.

You could change your rule like this (not 100% sure about ANTLR syntax, so you have to try yourself):

```
newTest : welcomeMessage? 'newhello' STRING ';' ;
```

Then your example should pass.

Comment: what I am interested is traverse single tree(may be like define start rule and include other rules as expr into it) to parse entire input and perform operations.